# A topological space is called a US-space provided that

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

A topological space is called a *US-space* provided that
each convergent sequence has a unique limit.

> Each Fréchet $US$-space $X$ is a $KC$-space.

Proof. Suppose that $x \in K$ where $K$ is a compact subspace of $X$. Because
X is a Fréchet space, there is a sequence $(k_n)_{n∈N}$ of points of $K$ converging to
$x$. Since $K$ is compact, that sequence has a cluster point $c$ in $K$. There is a subsequence of $(k_n)_{n∈N}$ converging to $c$ . Hence $x = c \in K$, because $X$ is a $US$-space. so $K$ is closed and then $X$ is a $KC$-space.

> **Why "there is a subsequence of $(k_n)_{n∈N}$ converging to $c$"**? How does it build?

Answer (score 1):

A US space is also $T_1$ since if $x$ is a point with another point $y$ in its closure then the constant sequence at $x$ converges to both $x$ and $y$, so by uniqueness of limits $x$ must equal $y.$ So points are closed.

Now, in a Fréchet-Urysohn space with the $T_1$-property a cluster point of a sequence is also a limit point of some subsequence (see [my answer to your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497511/cluster-point-in-frechet-urysohn-space-is-limit-point/497596#497596)).

Comment: Is $T_ 1$ -property necessary? which book is your references for my previous question?

Comment: I don't know if it's necessary, but it is sufficient. And I don't have a book as a reference.

Comment: What is exactly your definition of cluster point, here? I thought $x \in X$ is a cluster poinf of sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $( X,\tau)$ if for $ k \in ‎‎\mathbb{N}$ and open $G$ that contains $x$ ,$ G \cap \{ x_n : n\geq k \} \not= \emptyset$.is it right?

Comment: @fatemeh: That's right.