# Fréchet-Urysohn space

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

We know that if $p$ is the limit of a subsequence $(x_{n_{k}})$ of the sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$, then $p$ is a cluster point of the sequence.
For a sequential space, it does not hold that a cluster point of a sequence is the limit of a subsequence of it.

If we have a sequence $(x_n)$ in a  Fréchet-Urysohn space with a cluster point p, will this give us a convergent subsequence to p? How?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it will. By definition a Fréchet-Urysohn space is one in which the sequential closure of a set is equal to the closure of the set. Suppose that $X$ is Fréchet-Urysohn, $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ is a sequence in $X$, and $p$ is a cluster point of $\sigma$.

Let $\mathscr{B}_p$ be the set of open nbhds of $p$, and let $C_p=\bigcap\mathscr{B}_p$; $C_p=\{p\}$ if $X$ is $T_1$, but if $X$ is not $T_1$, it’s possible that $C_p\supsetneqq\{p\}$. Let $M=\{n\in\omega:x_n\in C_p\}$. If $M$ is infinite, $\langle x_n:n\in M\rangle$ is a subsequence of $\sigma$ converging to $p$, so we may assume that $M$ is finite. Let $m=1+\max M$, and let $\sigma'=\langle x_n:n\ge m\rangle$. Let $U$ be any open nbhd of $p$, and let $\ell\in\omega$; $p$ is a cluster point of $\sigma$, so there is an $n\ge\max\{m,\ell\}$ such that $x_n\in U$, so $p$ is a cluster point of $\sigma'$, and for all $n\ge m$ we have $x_n\notin C_p$. Thus, we may as well replace $\sigma$ by $\sigma'$ if necessary and assume that $x_n\notin C_p$ for all $n\in\omega$.

Let $A=\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$. $A\cap C_p=\varnothing$, so $p\notin A$. On the other hand, the fact that $p$ is a cluster point of the sequence $\sigma$ implies that $p$ is a limit point (or accumulation point) of the set $A$ and hence that $p\in\operatorname{cl}A$. $X$ is Fréchet-Urysohn, so $\operatorname{cl}A$ is the sequential closure of $A$; this means that there is a sequence $\langle a_k:k\in\omega\rangle$ in $A$ that converges to $p$. For each $k\in\omega$ there is an $n_k\in\omega$ such that $a_k=x_{n_k}$, and the sequence $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\omega\rangle$ converges to $p$.

This is almost what we want, but not quite: $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\omega\rangle$ might not be a subsequence of $\sigma$, because the sequence $\langle n_k:k\in\omega\rangle$ may not be increasing. I’ll leave it to you to show that $\langle n_k:k\in\omega\rangle$ has a strictly increasing subsequence; you’ll need to use the fact that for each $k\in\omega$ there is an open nbhd of $p$ that does not contain $x_{n_k}$.

**Note:** If we assume that $X$ is $T_1$, the argument can be simplified a bit; making $\sigma$ avoid the set $C_p$ is to take care of the possibility that $X$ is not $T_1$. It’s necessary to look at the set $A$ because the definition of Fréchet-Urysohn spaces imposes a condition on the closures of **sets**: I use the fact that $p$ is in the closure of the set $A$ to conclude that $p$ is in the sequential closure of $A$ and hence that some sequence in $A$ converges to $p$. To complete the proof one must then show that this sequence has a subsequence that is also a subsequence of the original $\sigma$; that’s the bit that I left for you.

Comment: @Alireza: I’ve expanded the explanation a bit; see if it helps.

Comment: can we take"$ x_{n_{0}} = a_0$ and $k_{r + 1} > k_{r}$ s.t $x _{n_{r + 1}} = a_{k_{r +1}}$ and we do this for all r > k " to get increasing sequence?

Comment: This seems to be the same reasoning as in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497511/cluster-point-in-frechet-urysohn-space-is-limit-point/497805#497805). So this implies that each countably compact Fréchet-Urysohn is sequentially compact.

Comment: @Stefan: More generally, countable compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness in sequential spaces. (I remember seeing your Arens space example, but I don’t think that I looked at the other question again after that. It is pretty much the same argument.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Are you sure? I know that it's true in sequential Hausdorff spaces, seeing a sketch of the proof in the paper [Spaces in which Sequences suffice](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm57/fm5717.pdf)

Comment: @Stefan: No, I was forgetting that Engelking assumes Hausdorffness when dealing with compactness properties.

Comment: @Brian M.Scott:(1): Is there special book to give me more explain about Fréchet space? (2) My definition for Fréchet is that " if $A \subseteq X$ and $x \in \overline{A}$, there is sequence of point in $A$ s.t  converge to $x$." which difference is there between $T_1$ and Fréchet

Comment: (1) There is some material on Fréchet spaces in Engelking’s *General Topology*. (2) Yes, that’s the definition of a Fréchet space. There really is no connection between the $T_1$ separation property and the Fréchet property: a $T_1$ space can be Fréchet or not Fréchet, and a Fréchet space can be $T_1$ or not $T_1$.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. under which condition are these spaces equal?(2) generally, the a sequential limit of a sequence is  a cluser point, does vice verse hole iff space is  Fréchet ?

Comment: @Alireza: You’re welcome. Do you mean Fréchet spaces and $T_1$ spaces? Those properties are so completely unrelated that I doubt that there’s any nice class of spaces in which they coincide.