# When do limits of subsequences coincide with limit points of the sequence?

Tags: general-topology

It is known that in a first countable space, any limit point $c$ of a sequence $x_n$ is the limit of some subsequence of $x_n$. This is not true in general as noted in this previous question [Accumulation points of sequences as limits of subsequences?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192463/accumulation-points-of-sequences-as-limits-of-subsequences).

My question is, does the converse hold? I.e., if a space $X$ has the property that for any sequence $x_n \in X$, every limit point of the sequence is the limit of some subsequence, does it follow that $X$ is first countable?

If not, does this property coincide with some other known notion? If it *does* coincide with some other known notion, I'd expect that it would be Urysohn-Frechet or sequential spaces, but I haven't been able to prove that.

Comment: These older questions seem to be related: [Cluster point of a sequence and limit point of some subsequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/104517) and [Cluster Point in Fréchet-Urysohn Space is Limit Point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/497511) And this one: [Fréchet-Urysohn space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/509728)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The converse does not hold.  Let $X=\omega_1+1=\omega_1\cup\{\omega_1\}$, where $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal, equipped with the order topology.  We claim this has the property described. Indeed, if $x$ is a limit point of $x_n$ and $x\neq \omega_1$, then $\{(y,x]\mid y<x\}$ forms a countable base at $x$ and we can deduce the property from that.

On the other hand if $\omega_1$ is a limit point for $x_n$ then $x_n$ must frequently equal $\omega_1$.  To see this, observe that otherwise there is some $N$ for which $\{x_n\mid n> N\}\cap \{\omega_1\}=\emptyset$, but then $\alpha=\bigcup_{n>N}x_n$ is a countable ordinal, hence less than $\omega$, and so
$$\{x_n\mid n> N\}\cap (\alpha,\omega_1]=\emptyset\text{,}$$
contradicting the assumption that $\omega_1$ is a limit point.

Since $x_n$ is frequently equal to $\omega_1$, we certainly have a subsequence that is constantly equal to $\omega_1$ and thus converges.

Note that $X$ is not first countable, as $\omega_1$ has no countable base.
Moreover, $X$ is not a Fréchet–Urysohn space, nor a sequential space of any type at all, since $\{x\in X\mid x<\omega_1\}$ is sequentially closed but not closed.

Thus while I do not know if there is some other characterization for this property, it is not one of the ones mentioned.

Comment: I'd change notation to use $\omega_1$ as $\omega$ is more typically the first infinite (countable) ordinal.

Comment: @StevenClontz thanks, my ordinals were a little rusty and I'd forgotten some of the standard conventions, I fixed it.

Comment: It's a good answer. I'm a little surprised that after some light searching I didn't find a name for this property, but I'd be more surprised if it isn't out there somewhere.